# Javafx spinner not updating properly -- how to debug Javafx source

Tags: javafx, clojure

I'm using Clojure to implement a JavaFX8 spinner for custom types.  The types (`defrecords`) represent distances of various units, such as um, mm, cm, m, km, inch, mil.  So a 10mm distance is `#millimeter{:value 10.0}`, and can be converted to cm using `(cm ...)` function, which returns `#centimeter{:value 1.0}`, etc.

Each instance of spinner is dedicated to showing a particular unit. For example I have one one spinner that always maintains its `ValueFactory` value using the millimeters defrecord.  When the user types a string such as `"10"`, it is taken as millimeters and displayed as `10.0`.  But when the user types a string such as `"10cm"`, it is converted to millimeters defrecord then displayed as `100.0`.

I have implemented `SpinnerValueFactory` for the spinner, and `StringConverter` with `toString` and `fromString` defined as needed.  Everything works great, except sometimes the spinner does not "take" the value when I press enter.

Specifically, if the user types in a string that is equivalent to the value already displayed (for example, `"10.0"` is displayed for millimeter spinner, and user types `"10mm"` or `"1cm"`) , then the entire chain of Listeners and var watches I have tied to this thing doesn't fire.  I think it's because after converting user's string to millimeters defrecord using, JavaFX determines it's already equal to the `ValueFactory` value, and decides not to fire the `ChangeListener`.  I can verify that nothing happens even from the REPL where I can forcibly set the value in the `ValueFactory`.

Questions:

1. How do I do step-through debug of Javafx source to verify this is happening?  I'm pretty crappy with Java, but I have NetBeans and the javafx source.
2. How do I get JavaFX to force its observables to update?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wound up putting an `InvalidationListener` instead of a `ChangeListener` on the observable.  This gets called even when the observable is set to the same value it already is.  This doesn't get the old value like `ChangeListener`, but I was able to work around that.